# What does section 5 of Creative Commons 4.0 means?

Tags: contract-law, liability

I am in no way a lawyer, and I am having trouble decoding this part of the creative commons license :

> Section 5 – Disclaimer of Warranties and Limitation of Liability.
>
> Unless otherwise separately undertaken by the Licensor, to the extent
> possible, the Licensor offers the Licensed Material as-is and
> as-available, and makes no representations or warranties of any kind
> concerning the Licensed Material, whether express, implied, statutory,
> or other. This includes, without limitation, warranties of title,
> merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose, non-infringement,
> absence of latent or other defects, accuracy, or the presence or
> absence of errors, whether or not known or discoverable. Where
> disclaimers of warranties are not allowed in full or in part, this
> disclaimer may not apply to You.
>
> To the extent possible, in no event
> will the Licensor be liable to You on any legal theory (including,
> without limitation, negligence) or otherwise for any direct, special,
> indirect, incidental, consequential, punitive, exemplary, or other
> losses, costs, expenses, or damages arising out of this Public License
> or use of the Licensed Material, even if the Licensor has been advised
> of the possibility of such losses, costs, expenses, or damages. Where
> a limitation of liability is not allowed in full or in part, this
> limitation may not apply to You.
>
> The disclaimer of warranties and
> limitation of liability provided above shall be interpreted in a
> manner that, to the extent possible, most closely approximates an
> absolute disclaimer and waiver of all liability.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use at your own risk

I'm letting you use this (presumably computer code or database, not a novel), but I'm not promising that it will work, and you can't sue me if it doesn't work. Admittedly, if the laws of your country will hold me liable for damage done by my crummy code, I have no choice other than to pay for those damages. But otherwise, I make no promises, I don't even promise that this work isn't copyright infringement. I don't even promise that I know of no errors or other defects. So you can't sue me. Unless, by law wherever you can sue me, I am not allowed to prevent myself from being sued by making this disclaimer.

That's the gist of the disclaimer.